What grammar pattern is being used in the phrase "but are you everywhere you should be"?
In this Youtube video, there's a following phrase:

... but are you everywhere you should be.

Suppose the caption is correct, I don't quite really get the meaning and also the grammar pattern being using here. Could you please help to set light on this?

"Are you [selling] in every place that you could find customers?" NB You mean "Can you throw some light on this?" To set light to something is to make it catch fire!

Ohm, that's right, I was misled by the context coming before this sentence.
